# Why does gcc not complain about htons() but complains about getaddrinfo() when compiled with -std=c99?

Tags: c, posix, c99

The following program compiles and runs fine even if compiled with `-std=c99`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", htons(1));
}
```

Here is the output.

```
$ gcc -std=c99 foo.c && ./a.out
256
```

But the following program leads to warning and error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
    struct addrinfo *res;
    getaddrinfo("localhost", NULL, NULL, &res);
    printf("%d\n", res->ai_flags);
}
```

Here are the warning and error.

```
$ gcc -std=c99 bar.c
bar.c: In function ‘main’:
bar.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getaddrinfo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     getaddrinfo("localhost", NULL, NULL, &res);
     ^
bar.c:10:23: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     printf("%d\n", res->ai_flags);
```

Why does the compiler not complain about `htons()` but complains about `getaddrinfo()` when compiled with `-std=c99`?

I am compiling this code with gcc 4.9.2 on Debian 8.3 system.

Comment: I know nothing about these libraries, but it seems like some library installation issue.

Comment: @Lundin This is not a library installation issue. I did not install these libraries. It came with the system. This is an issue about C99 vs. POSIX as I have already tagged in this question. The second code example would compile fine if I omit `-std=c99` from the compiler options.

Comment: getaddrinfo  did not exist in 1999

Comment: And what happens if you add `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`? The headers probably have a conditional that hides these declarations when in strict c99 mode.

Comment: @stark Neither did `htons`. Why does that compile then?

Comment: The only thing that would make C99 and ancient C is that C99 gives a diagnostic if there is no function declaration present, while ancient C would pretend that everything is fine and then try to make up a declaration, ie blatantly lie to the programmer. There is however nothing in C99 that would cause the missing struct declaration to behave differently. Out of curiosity, what happens if you compile with `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors`?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Yes, `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` compiles fine. My point of asking this question is: Why the difference in behaviour between compiling `htons` and compiling `getaddrinfo` when neither is in C99?

Comment: @LoneLearner: have a look at the declaration of `getaddrinfo` and `struct addrinfo` in your headers, and in particular, what ifdef's they are surrounded by, and paste it here.

Comment: @Lundin `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors bar.c` gets rid of the warning but `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` still appears.

Answer (score 5):

From the Linux [man pages for glibc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html):

> POSIX.1-2001. `htons()`

> POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008.  The getaddrinfo() function is documented
> in RFC 2553.

> Since glibc 2.22: _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 201112L

> Glibc 2.21 and earlier: _POSIX_C_SOURCE

To get the prototype for `getaddrinfo()` you need to specify which version of POSIX you want to use before you include the header, for example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 201112L
```

[RFC 2553](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2553#section-7) adds IPv6 support to the socket interface. The addition meant that new structs were added.
Since not all plkatforms implemented the new stuff at once there was a need to specify which version of the interface you need for stuff that had changed. `htons` is the same in all versions, so it doesn't care what version you request. `getaddrinfo` has changed due to RFC 2553, so you need to specify that you want/(can handle) the changed version.

As noted in the comments the required value for _POSIX_C_SOURCE varies between platforms. It seems that for gcc on RHEL6 it is sufficient to specify _POSIX_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1.

It would be great if someone could confirm whether _POSIX_SOURCE is a portable way to get the prototype for `getaddrinfo` on any POSIX system.

Comment: Or alternatively, pass it to the compiler via `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=201112L` without putting it in the beginning of the file.

Comment: Why do you recommend the particular value of `201112L` for `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`? On my system, I see that `/usr/include/features.h` defines `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to  `200809L` (also confirmed by preprocessing `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` with `gcc -E`). Also, why not recommend something like `#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1` which also seems to work?

Comment: Do you know why `getaddrinfo()` requires these macro definitions but `htons()` doesn't?

Comment: @LoneLearner The man page I happened to find when googling gave the value 201112L (I've added a link in my answer). Seems like the required value may vary depending on platform. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The value `201112L` in [man getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) looks like a typo in the man page because there is no such POSIX standard called POSIX.1-2011. [man feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) seems to indicate that the value should be `200112L`. There is no such value called `201112L` in the 2nd link.

Comment: per the man page for `getaddrinfo()`, there is a 'feature test macro that must be declared.  Here is the actual text from the man page: ` Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       getaddrinfo(), freeaddrinfo(), gai_strerror():
           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE`

Comment: @user3629249 **the** man page? There are other platforms than `gcc/Linux` and they have their own man pages.

Comment: True, there are other platforms, but `C` is `C` so the man page(s) will say the same usage details.   And since most `C` header files follow the `C` standard, the consideration about the 'feature test macro requirements' is the same usually because of the incorporation of the 'posiz' standards

Comment: @user3629249 If you check the man page for glibc that I linked in my answer you will see that the feature test macro requirements are not identical.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in `getaddrinfo` - it is in `struct addrinfo`. Implicit declaration of `gettaddrinfo` is a warning, not error. `struct addrinfo` is not declared and *that* is the error.

The struct is declared in `netdb.h` but is hidden under `ifdef __USE_POSIX`. There is a comment:

> /* Extension from POSIX.1g.  */

No such `ifdef` exists for `htons`.

Comment: By the way, I don't get any warning for the implicit declaration of `htons`. `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra foo.c` compiles successfully without any warning.

Comment: Yep, that's because it is actually declared. I was assuming that you forgot the headers completely. I have removed that part of my answer.

Comment: So that brings me back to the question: Why are these things arranged in this manner, i.e. why is it that with `-std=c99` `htons()` is declared but `getaddrinfo()` isn't even if the necessary headers are included?

Comment: Note that the implicit declaration would've been an issue if the return type were not `int` though.

Comment: That's why I thought that header file was not imported - `htons` program would have worked fine with implicit declaration. `getaddrinfo` one would work too if `struct addrinfo` would be defined. Or if it would not be dereferenced.